# Confusion about the rephrase of Recursion Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling, I'm confused about how he rephrases the **Recursion Theorem**.

First, he states the theorem:
[image]

Then he says:
[image]

Finally, he expresses the theorem in a more general term:
[image]

My question is: the author says "there exists a unique mapping $f^{n}: A → A$", but I feel like there are more than one mappings: $f^{0} : A → A, f^{1} : A → A, f^{2} : A → A,...$.

Many thanks for clarifying my doubt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you feel is exactly what the theorem says! It does **NOT** say that "there exists a unique mapping $f^n$ …". It says that

> For each $\color{blue}{n}\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ there exists a unique mapping $f^{\color{blue}{n}}:A\to A$ …

So all in all there are many these mappings, just as you said: there's one for $n=0$, one for $n=1$, one for $n=2$, etc.

Comment: Hi @zipirovich, I still don't understand how the author derives the mapping $f^{n}:A→ A$ from the sequence $(a_{n})_{n\in P}$. As a result, I also don't understand how the author derives $f^{s(n)}(a)=f(f^{n}(a))$ (or how can $f^{s(n)}$ is related to $f^{n}$). Please shed some lights on my confusion!

Comment: @leanhdung: $s(n)$ is the successor function on non-negative integers; in other words, $s(n)=n+1$. So the formula that defines $f^{s(n)}(a)=f(f^n(a))$ simply says that $f^{n+1}(a)=f(f^n(a))$, which is a pretty usual definition of the iterates of a function: to apply $f$ to some input $(n+1)$ times, we apply $f$ one more time -- $(n+1)$-st time -- to $f^n$, the $n$-fold iterate of the original function.

Comment: I have post much more clear questions at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616999/how-prof-d-j-h-garling-generalizes-the-theorem-of-recursion, please have a look!