# How does Prof D. J. H. Garling generalize recursion theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling, I'm not able to understand how he generalizes recursion theorem.

In the first step, he states the theorem:
[image]

Here, mapping $s:P→P$ satisfies *Peano’s axioms*.

In the second step, he reasons:
[image]

Finally, he gets the theorem in a more general form:
[image]

My confusion is that:

1. In the original theorem, for each $\bar{a}$, there exists a unique mapping $a:P → A$ such that $a_{0}=\bar{a}$ and $a_{s(n)}=f(a_{n})$ $\forall n\in P$. We substitute $P$ by $Z^{+}$. As a result, for each $\bar{a}$, there exists a unique mapping $a:Z^{+} → A$ such that $a_{0}=\bar{a}$ and $a_{s(n)}=f(a_{n})$ $\forall n\in Z^{+}$. However, I don't understand how the author derives the mapping $f^{n}:A → A$ from the mapping $a:Z^{+} → A$.
2. In the second step, the author lets $f^{n}(\bar{a})=a_{n}$. This means $f^{0}(\bar{a})=a_{0}$, $f^{1}(\bar{a})=a_{1}$, $f^{2}(\bar{a})=a_{2}$, ..., $f^{n}(\bar{a})=a_{n}$. From my understanding, he only defines $f^{0}, f^{1}, f^{2}, f^{3},..., f^{n}$ for only $\bar{a}$. I don't understand how the author defines $f^{0}, f^{1}, f^{2}, f^{3},..., f^{n}$ for the other elements in A.
3. $(f^{n}(\bar{a})=a_{n}$ and it is possible that $ran(a)\subsetneq A) → ran(f^{n})\subsetneq A$. How can $f^{n}$ be defined for all $a\in A$?

For the sake of clarity, there is a screenshot of full proof of recursion theorem by the author at [Possible typos in the proof of Recursion Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613220/possible-typos-in-the-proof-of-recursion-theorem).

Many thanks for clarifying my doubt!

Comment: Could you clarify what $P$ is? Re 2, I think $f^n$ is supposed to be provided by Theorem 1.8.2, and "$f^n(\bar a)=a_n$" is defining $a_n$, not $f^n$.

Comment: @stewbasic, I have just edited my post for clarity. Here, mapping $s:P→P$ satisfies *Peano’s axioms*. You said "$f^n(\bar a)=a_n$" is defining $a_{n}$, not $f^{n}$, so i wonder how $f^n$ is defined properly?

Comment: I thought the paragraph was proving Theorem 1.8.2 $\Rightarrow$ Theorem 1.8.1, but it's hard to tell without more context. Does the book provide a separate proof of Theorem 1.8.2?

Comment: @stewbasic, I have a screenshot of the full proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613220/possible-typos-in-the-proof-of-recursion-theorem, but there are some typos. Please be careful about them!

Comment: I assume this paragraph follows the proof in your screenshot? Then probably I am wrong, the paragraph is meant to show Theorem 1.8.1 $\Rightarrow$ Theorem 1.8.2. In that case we'd need to apply Theorem 1.8.1 to each $a\in A$. That is, define $f^n=\{(a(0),a(n))\mid a:\mathbf Z^+\to A,\,a\circ s=f\circ a\}$ and use Theorem 1.8.1 to show $f^n$ is a function.

Comment: Yes. In the textbook, the order is: Theorem 1.8.1 ⇒ Proof (I just gave you that link) ⇒ Theorem 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, to construct $f^n$ we must specify $f^n(\bar a)$ for each $\bar a\in A$. So for each $\bar a\in A$, apply Theorem 1.8.1 to obtain a sequence $a$ (this depends on $\bar a$), and let $f^n(\bar a)=a(n)$.

More formally we could define $f^n$ as
$$
  \{p\in A\times A:\text{there exists }g:\mathbf Z^+\to A\text{ with }g\circ s=f\circ g,\,g(0)=p_1,\,g(n)=p_2\}.
$$
I claim that for all $a\in A$, $|f^n\cap(\{a\}\times A)|=1$. Indeed fix $a\in A$. By Theorem 1.8.1, there exists $g:\mathbf Z^+\to A$ with $g\circ s=f\circ g$ and $g(0)=a$. Then $(a,g(n))\in f^n$. Conversely if $p\in f^n\cap(\{a\}\times A)$ then there exists $g':\mathbf Z^+\to A$ with $g'\circ s=f\circ g$, $g'(0)=p_1=a$ and $g'(n)=p_2$. By the uniqueness in Theorem 1.8.1, $g'=g$, so $p_2=g(n)$. Thus $f^n\cap(\{a\}\times A)=\{(a,g(n))\}$. This shows $f^n$ is a function.

Comment: By my understanding of your answer, I get: 1. Mapping $f^{n}$ depends on $a\in A$. This means for each $a\in A$, there exists a unique mapping $f^{n}$. 2. For each $a\in A$, $f^{n}=\{(a,p)\in A\times A:\exists g:\mathbf Z^+\to A\text{ s.t }g\circ s=f\circ g,\,p=g(n)\}.$ Is it right?

Comment: I don't know what $|f^n\cap(\{a\}\times A)|=1$ means? Please elaborate!

Comment: No, $f^n$ does not depend on $a$. $f^n(a)$ depends on $a$. I defined $f^n$ as a subset of $A\times A$, so $f^n\cap(\{a\}\times A)$ is also a subset of $A\times A$, and I prove it has one element. In other words, for each $a\in A$ there is a unique $b\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in f^n$; this ensures $f^n$ is a function.

Comment: I'm now clear. Many thanks for you!